# How to be DRY in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, dry

I'm developing a mobile app using PhoneGap & jQuery Mobile. I'd like to keep my view files DRY. How do I achieve this in jQuery Mobile? Should I just put every page element in one HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, jQuery mobile is designed for  that and I is the best approach to be followed.

you can have something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquerymobilelibrary.js"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header"><h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput2">Title</label>
            <input name="" id="textinput2" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <a data-role="button" href="#page2">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header"><h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- Content is empty -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To switch between pages programmatically in JS you can use

```
<script>
  $.mobile.changePage('#page2')
</script>
```

In jquery mobile [site](http://jquerymobile.com/) there is a simple but cool drag-and-drop UI builder to explore what the JQM library can do.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So everything in a single HTML file? I can live with that, I think. What if some pages have the same header or footer? How do I keep that DRY?

Comment: Yes, you can. :) It's quite easy to maintain. If they have same header/footer you can use the data-id property with same id. 
Check this out: http://goo.gl/MmktFF and try it here: http://goo.gl/wobqh6 (if it helps you, mark as correct answer :])

Comment: I think that's to make the header/footer persistent, right? I'm trying to reuse the same header in various pages. My question deals with being DRY.

Comment: You could achieve this by injecting pages and/or make changes dynamically. You still can attached event listeners and manipulate DOM.